# Python: Subtract Previous Row Index from Current Row, Same Index [Without Pandas]

Tags: python, list, data-structures, time

I am a Python (and programming as a whole) novice. I have seen hundreds of questions about this but all use the `pandas` package for data analysis. I already have several hundred lines of code which have not used `pandas` so I want to avoid `pandas` if possible, or if I can restructure my data using `pandas`, I am open for suggestions.

I have several thousand lines of raw data made into lists as `entries`. I use `column` to create another list from `entries` for simplicity of executing my functions.

I want to subtract an index (`entries[2]`) of a previous row from the same index of the current row. I see two ways of completing this:

current line `entries[2]` - previous line `entries[2]`

or

current line `Elapsed Time` - previous line `Elapsed Time`

Sample Raw Data:

```
1 c    4977321 200 200 007 003 033 001 002 003 092 001 
2 d    4977789 010 120 100 100 
3 e    4977816 175 194 000 
4 f    4977868 225 220 100 300 001
```

Here, index 2 is time (i.e. 4977321)

My Code looks like this:

```
f = input('Type in File Name: ')  # What Raw Data log do we want to analyze?


def function():
    print_string = ''
    # do something with the data
    print_string += 'Time Delta: ' + str(delta_time)
    if 'Time Delta' in print_string:
        print(print_string)


initial_time = None  # Establishes 0 start point for time (not all captures start at 0ms)
with open(f, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        entries = line.split()  # Organizes data line as a list, entries as indices
        column = [int(v) for v in entries[3:]]  
        delta_time = int(entries[2]) - time
        time = int(entries[2])  # Time expressed in milliseconds
        if initial_time is None:
            initial_time = time
            delta_time = 0
        elap_time = time - initial_time  # Expressed as elapsed time from start of capture in milliseconds
        function()

f.close()
```

I have left out the bulk of the body of my code (entirely functions) as I did not see it a necessary piece of information.

I want the code to determine a value for `delta_time` and so it can print after executing the function. I would like the output to look like:

```
Time Delta: #  (nothing here, no previous line)
Time Delta: #  4977789 - 4977321
Time Delta: #  4977816 - 4977789 
Time Delta: #  4977868 - 4977816
```

FYI, I used `elap_time` in my function when printing as well, just did not include it here.

Comment: Why do you want to torture yourself by not using pandas?

Comment: @coldspeed For a long time I had issues installing packages. It wasn't until recently that I finally troubleshot the issue and had pandas installed. Too late to go back now in my opinion.. though pandas would have saved me hours of coding/learning lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare time before the loop with some default value

```
time = 0
```

Afterwards, invert delta_time line with time and do:

```
delta_time = int(entries[2]) - time 
time = int(entries[2])
```

Comment: Thank you! One issue: The very first `delta_time` is not 0. Because `time` does not start at 0 (i.e. the first line's `entries[2]` is not 0), the first `delta_time` is now `entries[2]` of the very first line of data. Any way to make it so that the very first result of `delta_time` = 0?

Comment: You could use your `initial_time` if statement to do that. Just add `delta_time = 0` one line below `initial_time=time`. It will override the value of `delta_time` in the case `initial_time`is not set, i.e., the first line.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works as expected but throws an error in my IDE (PyCharm). The error highlights the previously established delta_time variable and says `Redeclared 'delta_time' defined above without usage`. I updated the code in the question post to reflect the code I have implemented using your suggestions. Is this an issue to be worried about? I am not understanding it since the output is working as expected.

Comment: It might be just a warning to prevent same variable name usage. But, since you are purposedly overwriting the variable, I wouldn't be worried.